# Calculating absolute precision confidence number from Dilution of Precision indicators from GPS receiver

Tags: gps, nmea

End-user GPS receivers typically show an absolute confidence indication, such as *Within 25 Metres*, for the calculated position.

I am parsing NMEA data from a GPS unit and wan't to calculate a similar quality of service indication. The NMEA data exposes a Dilution of Precision indication (actually, one for both the horizontal and vertical position, HDOP/VDOP).

How do I go from DOP value(s) to a concrete confidence measurement (say, metres)?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

All the GPS receiver is doing, is multiplying the [dilution of precision](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dilution_of_precision_%28GPS%29) figure by the resolution of the device.

Of course, GPS positions can still be awry, with a high confidence of the location, if you have a good signal strength from satellites in a non-optimum configuration (sometimes referred as canyon effect)

Comment: lol, same links