# Translating hdop, pdop and vdop to metric accuracy from given NMEA strings

Tags: gps, accuracy, nmea

How can I translate dilution of precision to a metric unit?

For example: say I got 1.2 in hdop from NMEA sentence of my GPS receiver,
in what should I multiply to get a metric accuracy? Just like the way Android or other platforms do.

It may be a duplicate ([This link](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/377/calculating-absolute-precision-confidence-number-from-dilution-of-precision-indi)), but it was said: "**All the GPS receiver is doing, is multiplying the dilution of precision figure by the resolution of the device.**"

I didn't catch that, what is the "resolution of the device"?

Comment: If GPS device in optimal conditions has an accuracy of 5 m, then with hdop of 1.2 the estimation of accuracy at that moment is 6 m.

Comment: So what you are saying is that I need to assume the best accuracy that my gps can give is 5meters and then multiply the hdop by 5 to get the current fix accuracy... ok thank you :)

Comment: The best accuracy is what the manufacturer announces in the specifications. It can be 5 m or 3 m or something else.

Comment: @user30184 is the “best accuracy” shown in the NMEA data? If not, how can we do this programmatically?

Comment: @user30184 it's being said that best accuracy is one of your gps device specifications, it's not determinable in NMEA sentences, it's typically 3 or 5 meters in almost all GPS devices.